# Syntax error, "except pygame.error"

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.4, except

I am a python and pygame noob, looked up a tutorial for loading sprites in to my game, and I'm getting syntax error for this this line of code

```
    except pygame.error, message:
                   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the entire block of code:

```
def load_image(self, image_name):

    try:
        image = pygame.image.load(image_name)

    except pygame.error, message:

        print "Cannot load image: " + image_name
        raise SystemExit, message

    return image.convert_alpha()
```

I didn't check if the tutorial was for python 3.4.2 or not, has the syntax changed?

Or is there something else wrong with my code?

Comment: That is python2 syntax

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `as message` in python3 and    `raise SystemExit(message)`:

```
def load_image(self, image_name):  
    try:
        image = pygame.image.load(image_name)    
    except pygame.error as message:   
        print("Cannot load image: " + image_name)
        raise SystemExit(message)    
    return image.convert_alpha()
```

Also `print` is a `function` in `python3` so you need parens.

Comment: No worries, if you are following a tutorial for python2 there are probably going to be quite a few changes needed

Comment: I noticed now while debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Writing `except pygame.error, message:` is only valid in Python 2.  In Python 3, you must instead write:

```
except pygame.error as message:
```